# Unpivot on a column that has dash on it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my query in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
INSERT VMP_Staging_Products_Temporary
    (FRM_ID, ITEM_ID, ItemDesc, NUMBER_ITEM)
    SELECT upvt.FARM_ID,
    p.REC_ITEM_CODE,
    p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A,
    upvt.NUMBER_ITEM
    FROM VMP_Staging  AS f
    UNPIVOT
    (
        NUMBER_ITEM
        FOR ItemDesc IN ([KHALAS], [FARDH], [OTHER_LULU], [KHENAIZI], [BOUMAAN], [BARHI], [JESH_KHARMA], [REZIZ]
        , [JABRI], [ANBARET_AL_MADINA], [SHISHI], [DABBAS], [NABTET_SAIF], [KHEDRAWI], [HILALI], [MAKTOUMY]
        , [NAMISHI], [SULTANAH], [BAQLAT_AL_TAWAA], [BAQLAT_AL_DAHLA], [BAQLAT_AL_RARENJA], [SUKARY], [SAQEI], [ABU_ZEBED]
        , [MAJDOUL], [SHABIBI], [YOUWANI], [YARDI], [KHADI], [HATIMI], [NEGHAL], [OTHER_SAYER])
    ) AS upvt
    INNER JOIN REC_ITEM AS P
    on p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A  = upvt.ItemDesc
```

As you see, I am doing a join between `REC_ITEM` table and the result of the unpivot.

The problem happens in the column names that has `_` like `ABU_ZEBED` where the value in the `REC_ITEM` is `abu zebed`

How can I solve it please?

#### Update 1

If there is a way to do that using c# code, it is good too. because this is a stored procedure called from c# so if there is solution to deal with this in c#, I would like that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether it's a regular pattern or not, but at least:

```
INNER JOIN REC_ITEM AS P
    on replace(p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A, ' ', '_')  = upvt.ItemDesc
```

Performance will be terrible, though.

Comment: isn't there a way to change the result of the unpivot ?

Comment: and your solution still gives me 22 results instead of 31

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec - are you sure these characters in REC_ITEM are indeed spaces (that is, `char(32)`)? Try to check its contents, say, like this: `select sq.Orig, sq.Upd, case when sq.Orig = sq.Upd then 1 end as [Equal] from (
select r.rec_item_name_a as [Orig], replace(r.rec_item_name_a, char(32), char(95)) as [Upd]
from rec_item r
) sq;`

Comment: Disregard the previous one, please. This should work: `select * from rec_item where rec_item_name_a = 'ABU' + char(32) + 'ZEBED';` If anything will show up, it means there is indeed an ordinary space between the name parts; if not, then it's some other character there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining in multiple ways:

```
on p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A = upvt.ItemDesc or
   p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A = replace(upvt.ItemDesc, '_', ' ')
```

Alternatively, remove both spaces and underscores from both sides:

```
on replace(replace(p.REC_ITEM_NAME_A, '_', ''), ' ', '') =
   replace(replace(upvt.ItemDesc, '_', ''), ' ', '')
```

Comment: I tried your first solution but still the same, I got 22 value instead of 31 value

Comment: the performance is bad, isn't there a way to correct the result of the unpivot?